# apply bullet style to a label using C#

Tags: c#, label

I am displaying a message on a asp label when user is successfully saved. I want  to append a bullet in starting of the message. So, I tried the following code but it coluld not help me.

lblSuccessMsg.Text = BulletStyle.Disc + " '" + obj.record + "' saved successfully.";

the output of the message is :

'Record' saved successfully.

How can i do the same using C#.

Comment: That is most definitely not how you use `BulletStyle`.

Answer (score 21):

In C#, you could simply add the bullet in your string by its unicode number.

```
lblSuccessMsg.Text = "\u2022 '" + obj.record + "' saved successfully.";
```

Comment: Hi..marcel ...it worked for me..but how can i apply style(bold,2px) for the bullet

Comment: @karthik: You can't format parts of a label's text. Use WPF if you want the same flexibility as in HTML.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to Marcel Gheorghita's answer there's some more unicode bullet chars:

```
‣ \u2023 (TRIANGULAR BULLET)
◦ \u25E6 (WHITE BULLET)
◉ \u25C9 (FISHEYE)
■ \u25A0 (BLACK SQUARE)
□ \u25A1 (WHITE SQUARE)
❏ \u274F (LOWER RIGHT DROP-SHADOWED WHITE SQUARE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do the following:

`lblSuccessMsg.Text = "<span style='background: url(Images/DotImage.png) no-repeat 1px 1px'>"+obj.record+" saved successfully</span>";`

It will be more convenient,because first upon u want to show  only one line,
secondly it will be more attractive and finally easily customizable,